# Function that expects 3d list and count of elements in Python

Tags: python

Do you have ideas on how I can create a function that expects a 3D list and counts the elements as well the unique elements.

For example the following list:

`list_3d = [[[1,5],[7,3],[1,5,8]]]`

The count of elements should be 7 and the count of unique ones - 5.

Comment: Please, show what you have tried.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how do it and I can't find any information

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are a beginner.

Therefore, the best practice is coding from scratch.

Here is the answer, please study well:

```
from numpy import unique


def main(list_3d):
    list_len = 0
    list_uniq = []
    for i in list_3d:
        for j in i:
            for m in j:
                list_len += 1
                if m not in list_uniq:
                    list_uniq.append(m)
    return list_len, list_uniq


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_list_3d = [[[1, 5], [7, 3], [1, 5, 8]]]
    input_list_3d_len = unique(input_list_3d)
    assert(input_list_3d_len.size == 3)
    list_length, list_unique = main(input_list_3d)
    print("List length: {}".format(list_length))
    print("List unique count: {}".format(len(list_unique)))
```

Output will be:

```
List length: 7

List unique count: 5
```

As an exercise, you can implement the same operation using `built-in` methods

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: `a function that expects a 3D list` - does your answer meet that requirement?

Comment: Is this ok? @wwii

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one question - how could be checked that the function expects 3d matrix?

Comment: You can use `numpy` 's `unique` method. Then use `assert` method to check the size. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to get the length then use the `set` of that to get the length of the unique elements.

```
from itertools import chain

list_3d = [[[1,5],[7,3],[1,5,8]]]

flattened = list(chain.from_iterable(*list_3d))

length = len(flattened)
unique = len(set(flattened))

print(length, unique)
```

Result:

```
7, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

> create a function that expects a 3D list
>
> - how could be checked that the function expects 3d matrix?

Here is a function that will check if a nested list is nested exactly three deep (without using any *external* libraries). Wasn't sure of your requirements but based on your example it only considers lists within lists.

```
def chk(a):
    w = isinstance(a,list)
    if w:
        x = all(isinstance(obj,list) for obj in a)
    else:
        return False
    if x:
        y = all(isinstance(obj,list) for item in a for obj in item)
    else:
        return False
    if y:
        z = any(isinstance(obj,list) for item in a for thing in item for obj in thing)
    else:
        return False
    return not z
```

If that is too verbose it can be refactored:

```
def chk(a):
    if not isinstance(a,list):
        return False
    if not all(isinstance(obj,list) for obj in a):
        return False
    if not all(isinstance(obj,list) for item in a for obj in item):
        return False
    return not any(isinstance(obj,list) for item in a for thing in item for obj in thing)
```

---

```
In [12]: chk([[1],[2]])    # 2-d
Out[12]: False

In [13]: chk([[[1]],[[2]]])    # 3-d
Out[13]: True

In [14]: chk([[[1]],[[2],3]])    # not quite 3-d
Out[14]: False

In [15]: chk([[[[1]]],[[[2]]]])    # 4-d
Out[15]: False
```

Then if you want your function can raise a ValueError if someone tries to sneek something past you.

```
In [18]: if not chk([1,2]):
    ...:     raise ValueError('Only 3-d arrays please')
    ...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-53fc36f743cb>", line 2, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Only 3-d arrays please')

ValueError: Only 3-d arrays please
```